# Temperature Conversion python function

Tags: python

**I am trying to find the solution to this problem for 2 hours already i am not sure what to type to a function like this?**

```
num = input ('Which Degree Temperature would you like to convert? ')
corf = raw_input ('Is the temperature Fahrenheit Degree or is it Celsius?(Type "f" for Fahrenheit or "c" for Celsius)')
def max(num,corf):
    if corf == 1 :
        return num
        Celsius = (num - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
        print str(num) + " Fahrenheit is equal to " + str(Celsius)+ " Celsius or " + ('%0.1f degrees Celsius ' %(Celsius)) + 'to one decimal place '
    elif corf == 2 :
        return num
        Fahrenheit = (num * 9.0 / 5.0 ) + 32  
        print str(num) + " Celsius is equal to " + str(Fahrenheit)+ " Fahrenheit or " + ('%0.1f degrees Celsius ' %(Celsius)) + 'to one decimal place '
    else:
        return 'Error'
```

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 1):

In each `if` or `elif` statement, change a number into the correct string:

```
if corf == "f":        
    return num
    Celsius = (num - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
    print str(num) + " Fahrenheit is equal to " + str(Celsius)+ " Celsius or " + ('%0.1f degrees Celsius ' %(Celsius)) + 'to one decimal place '
elif corf == "c":
    return num
    Fahrenheit = (num * 9.0 / 5.0 ) + 32  
    print str(num) + " Celsius is equal to " + str(Fahrenheit)+ " Fahrenheit or " + ('%0.1f degrees Celsius ' %(Celsius)) + 'to one decimal place '
```

Why? Because the only input for `corf` should only be "f" or "c". Now each entry should be matched to the right code, as seen above.

Comment: Um... that's one issue, the other big issue is that he's returning num before he does the math.  (There's also an issue that he copied and pasted badly, shadowed a builtin (max), and doesn't show calling it which frequently people forget to do)